# declaration of NSArray and pointers question about safety?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

The desired result is to build 10 columns into NSArray.  The following works with what looks like the desired result.
But am I playing with fire here?

```
NSArray **ppp;

int m=10;

ppp = calloc(m, sizeof(NSArray));

ppp[0]=[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                 @"1",
                 @"2",
                 @"3",
                 ];

ppp[1]=[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
            @"a1",
            @"b2",
            @"c3",
            @"d4",
            nil
            ];

NSLog(@"array test: %@   %@", [ppp[1] objectAtIndex:3], [ppp[0] objectAtIndex:2]);
```

thanks

Comment: Why not just use an NSArray of NSArrays? I'd avoid using the approach in your provided code - the calloc is definitely not needed.

Comment: I don't think you can do NSArray of NSArray.  I think it has to be NSMutableArray of NSArray ??

Comment: +1 for interesting question, and for living on the edge!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should, if you intend to, do

```
ppp = calloc(m, sizeof(NSArray *));
```

but taking this path will involve manual memory management of the array of arrays. Why don't you use an `NSMutableArray` instance.

```
NSMutableArray * masterArray = [NSMutableArray array];
[masterArray addObject:[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                 @"1",
                 @"2",
                 @"3",
                 ]];

.....

NSLog(@"array test: %@ ", [[masterArray objectAtIndex:1] objectAtIndex:3]);
```

Comment: It appears to be more convenient to use NSMutableArray to be able to "addObject", otherwise if I know the number of columns why not use malloc/calloc.

Comment: Mainly because it handles the memory management for us. If you want to optimize as you know the size of the array beforehand, you can use `arrayWithCapacity:` method to initialize the mutable array to allocate the required amount of memory.

Answer (score 3):

It should be `sizeof(id)`, but otherwise it's correct code. But there is some "blow-up" potential there, since it will make memory management much more complicated and error-prone then using an NSArray (as C arrays are completely ignorant of Objective-C's memory management requirements). Unless you've profiled and found it necessary, I would question doing this.

Answer (score 1):

Your calloc is all wrong.  If you want a buffer with 10 NSArray objects in it, do:

```
NSArray** ppp;
int m = 10;
ppp = calloc(m, sizeof(NSArray*));
```

...

The problem is that sizeof(int) != sizeof(id) on some architectures.  You're short-sheeting yourself, you will smash your heap and you will hit a malloc exception when you have written past the end of your array.  In addition, the error will be difficult to find.

I agree with InsertWittyName: just make an NSArray of NSArray's.  It's easier and safer.